# Why does 한 is spelled "o*an" but is said "han"?

Tags: hangul

I'm fairly sure this question has been asked dozens of times but, since I just started learning Korean I'm very confused about the most appropriate way to look up pronunciation.

I went through the basics of Hangul and I can't seem to find any explanation anywhere to why "한" is said "han".

I tried translating "Korean" to Korean and it gave me "한국어". So, I tried to say it and my mouth gave something like "oan gugn eu". But Google says it "hangug-eo". I really don't understand this "han" start.

Where does the "ㅗ" go?

I know that google translate isn't a perfect tool for learning languages, far from it, but I'm fairly sure I had already noticed this problem in a korean speaker's speech on a youtube video ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where does the "ㅗ" go?

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but there's no 'ㅗ' in "한".

the letter 'ㅎ' is not 'ㅗ' + 'ㅇ' - it's just one unit, 'ㅎ', in its own right.

so it's super simple -

ㅎ = 'h'
ㅏ = 'a' 
ㄴ = 'n'

so "한" is pronounced "han".

ㅎ can appear different depending on the font - e.g. it often looks like this:

[image]

Comment: HAAAAA I just understood that ㅎis a different way to write the picture you posted! IT'S A DIFFERENT FONT ! Wow okay makes sense. Thanks a lot! 고마워요

Comment: Right, there’s two ways of writing ㅎ.